Understanding proof of the Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, Chap V. (2.4) Theorem ( The norm residue symbol over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ )
I am reading proof of next theorem of Neukirch's Algebraic number theory ( Chapter V ). Can anyone who have the Neukrich's book help ? :


I am trying to understand the underlined statements. I can't understand it with my current knowledge.
Q.1. ) Why can we assume $u\in \mathbb{N}$ and $(u,p)=1$, by using the density of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
Q.2. ) Why $d_K(\tilde{\sigma}) = 1 $ and $\tilde{\sigma}|_L = \sigma$ and where the condition " the fixed field $\Sigma$ of $\tilde{\sigma}$ is totally ramified ( defined as in his book p.286 ) " is used in the proof ?
Q.3. ) And in the third underlined statment, he wrotes that "assume $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\varphi:=\varphi_L$ have been extended continuously to the completion $\hat{L}$ of $\tilde{L}$, " . Where the assumption is used ?
Q.4. ) And finally, for the fourth underlined statement, why $\pi_{\Sigma} := \theta(\lambda)$ is prime element ( as a prime element, it is defined in his book p.289 ) ?

For your first question :
Suppose the claim is proven for integers coprime to p.
By continuity of the norm residue symbol (that we will denote by f to shorter the notation $(,\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta)|\mathbf{Q}_p))$, $f^{-1}(f(u))$ is open in $\mathbf{Q}_p^*$. Because $u=u_{0}+u_{1}p+u_{2}p^2+...$ is a unit and because inversion of $p$-adic numbers is continuous, we can consider an open set $u+p^m\mathbf{Z}_p$ such that the inverse of any $p$-adic number in it differ with $u^{-1}$ by a term in $p^n\cdot \mathbf{Z}_p$ (because $1+p^k \cdot \mathbf{Z}_p$ form a basis of neighbourhood of $1$), any integer in this open set is coprime to p and for them :
$\zeta^{u^{-1}}=\zeta^{k^{-1}}$
Because $u^{-1}$ and $k^{-1}$ would differ by an element in $p^n\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $\zeta$ is a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity. Therefore the claim for general u would follow because we can choose an integer k in the intersection of the two open sets and we get :
$(u,\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta)|\mathbf{Q}_p)=f(u)=f(k)=\zeta^{k^{-1}}=\zeta^{u^{-1}}$
For your second question :
$d_K$ is a homomorphism, $d_K(\phi_L)$ is $1$ because of the isomorphism between $Gal(\tilde{L}/L)$ and $Gal(\tilde{K}/K)$ which commutes with projection to the Galois group of the residue class field (this exists because we can decomposed $\tilde{L}$ into two subextensions $L$ and $\tilde{K}$ such that their intersection is K) so we get :
$d_K(\phi_L)=d_K(\phi_K)=1$
and $d_K(\sigma)$ is $0$ because as L is totally ramified, $\sigma$ acts as the identity on the maximal unramified extension of K and we get :
$d_K(\sigma)=d_K(\sigma|_{\tilde{K}})=d_K(Id)=0$
So we conclude that $d_K(\tilde{\sigma})=1$ because it is the sum of the two values seen above.
$\tilde{\sigma}|_{L}$ is $\sigma$ because $\phi_L$ is the identity on L because it is in $Gal(\tilde{L}/L)$.
The condition on $\Sigma$ is used in a way that is not stated explicitly by Neukirch. Because $L$ and $\Sigma$ are totally ramified and because $\tilde{L}=\tilde{\Sigma}$ (4.5), we have isomorphisms :
$Gal(L/K) \cong Gal(\tilde{L}/\tilde{K})=Gal(\tilde{\Sigma}/\tilde{K})\cong Gal(\Sigma/K)$
So that the degree of $\Sigma/K$ is also $p^{n-1}(p-1)$. Therefore $\pi_{\Sigma}$ and its powers generates $\Sigma/K$ and we conclude that it must be prime because it can't be of valuation $0$ in $\Sigma$ because it is a root of P(x) so P($\pi_{\Sigma}$) should be congruent to $0$ mod p, but P(x) is congruent to a power of X mod p and a power of an element of valuation $0$ is never $0$ mod p so we would get a contradiction. Also it cannot be of valuation more than 1 because $\pi_{\Sigma}$ and it's powers generate $\Sigma$ and as they would have valuation greater than one, they wouldn't be able to generate a prime element (a prime element is an element of valuation $1$), which is again a contradiction.
For your third question :
This assumption is only used when Neukirch applies 2.3, in this corollary we need to work with the completion of the fields.
For your fourth question :
This has been answered in my answer for your second question.
As you have probably noticed, this does not seem to be an easy proof.
EDIT :
Here are answers for some questions in the comments.
First, proving the continuity of the norm residue symbol is done in the following manner:
A basis of the (discrete) topology on the galois group consists of the singletons {$g$}, to prove continuity it will suffice to prove that $f^{-1}(g)$ is open for any $g$ in the galois group ($f$ denotes the norm residue symbol). We have for any $x$ in the field $K$ that maps on $g$ that $f^{-1}(g)=x\cdot N_{L/K}$ where $N_{L/K}$ is the subgroup of norms, by continuity of multiplication, it suffices to prove that $N_{L/K}$ is an open subgroup of $K^*$ but this has already been proved in (1.4) at the page 321 of Neukirch.
For your comment about Q.2, you are right, the intersection is nonempty because $u$ is in both (it is in $f^{-1}(f(u))$ because it maps to $f(u)$, it is in $u+p^m \cdot \mathbf{Z}_p$ because $0$ is in $\mathbf{Z}_p$). Next, any integer of the form $u+p^{m}\mathbf{Z}_{p}$ is of the form $u_{0}+p\cdot a$ where $a$ is an integer and $u_{0}$ is between $1$ and $p-1$, because this number is not divisible by $p$, it is coprime to $p$.
To answer your Q.4 in the comments, this follows almost by definition, if two p-adic integers $a$ and $b$ differ by a $n$-th power of $p$ and $\zeta$ is a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity, we have :
$\zeta^a=\zeta^{b+p^n \cdot r}=\zeta^{b}\cdot(\zeta^{p^n})^r=\zeta^{b}\cdot(1)^r=\zeta^{b}$
for some $p$-adic integer $r$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
